# How to utilise payload instead of params in Taskqueue?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unit-testing, post

Within my unitest when I attempt the following POST; I get the params within the `request.base_url`. I would like to have it within `request.form`. How do I achieve that?

```
self.taskqueue_stub = apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy.GetStub('taskqueue')

tasks = self.taskqueue_stub.GetTasks("postios")
self.assertEqual(len(tasks), 1)
task = tasks[0]
params = base64.b64decode(task["body"])
headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
response = self.client.post(task["url"], params, headers=headers)
```

I found a way to pass it as data: `request.data`, but thats not good enough.

```
response = self.client.post(task["url"], data=params, headers=headers)
```

The reason I have to do this, is the way I add the task in my code.

```
taskqueue.Task(url='/worker',
                               params={"json_records": jsonified_task_records,
                                       "user": user.key.urlsafe()}
                               ).add(queue_name='postios')
```

Hence within the `/worker` view I expect to find the params in `request.form`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `payload` instead of `params`.

```
params = {"json_records": jsonified_task_records,
                          "user": user.key.urlsafe()}
taskqueue.Task(url='/worker',
                          payload=json.dumps(params)
                          ).add(queue_name='postios')
```

Now I always have it as `request.data` within my `/worker` view so that both unit tests and production code can expect to find it there.

Beware that `payloads` is unicode in this case and nested json structure needs to be converted once again via `json.loads`.

e.g. `/worker` view:

```
    jsons = json.loads(request.data)
    user_hash = jsons['user']
    json_records = json.loads(jsons['json_records']) # jsons['json_records'] is unicode
```